# how to show a fragment layout on full screen and overlap all the layout of mainactivity.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on a application which has MainActivity and 3 fragments.
on Main activity xml file there is noActionBar but there is a Linear Layout for back Button and another layout for my fragments to show the contents of fragments.
Now I want to show two fragments on the desired layout of mainactivity which I am doing and working perfectly file and third fragment where I am showing a video but want to show full on screen and should overlap all the layouts of main activity including back button layout.
for this fragment video is showing below the back button layout.

how can I achieve full screen video play ?

**NOte: Please dont ask me why I put back button layout.(this is my requirement)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your "not-action-bar" layout's visibility to View.GONE.